# How do I prove that $r(3,t+1) ≥ 3t$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> For each $t ≥ 2$, show that a $t$-regular Ramsey graph has
>   $$r(3,t+1) ≥ 3t$$

---

I'm stuck on where to go with this question. I've tried using what few theorems I know, but I've gotten caught up with inequalities that are not helping with anything, such as $r(3,t+1)≤r(3,t)+r(2,t+1)=r(3,t)+t+1$.

Comment: You might remind us, what a $t$-regular Ramsey graph is, and what your symbols $r$ and $t$ stand for.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If you do a proof by induction during the inductive step don't you end up with inequalities that aren't facing useful directions: $r(3,t+2)≤r(3,t+1)+r(2,t+2)=r(3,t+1)+t+2 ≥3t+t+2≥3(t+1)$?

Comment: @L.Q. The answer to the linked question has a nice construction showing the inequality you want.